# How to import other types in to a typescript .d.ts module

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings, gl-matrix

I have a custom `.d.ts` file for an external module that looks like

```
declare module 'vertices-bounding-box' {
  export default function boundingBox(positions: [number,number,number][]): [number, number]
}
```

Instead of `[number,number,number]` I would like to use a type from another module like:

```
import { vec3 } from 'gl-matrix';

declare module 'vertices-bounding-box' {
  export default function boundingBox(positions: vec3[]): [number, number]
}
```

TSC complains when I add the import statement for `vec3` saying:

```
Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'vertices-bounding-box' resolves to an untyped
module at '/Users/kevzettler/code/hypeworks/node_modules/vertices-bounding-box/index.js', which cannot be augmented. [2665]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just showed the most prevalent use case for [import types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#import-types) in TypeScript:

> Modules can import types declared in other modules. But non-module global scripts cannot access types declared in modules. Enter import types.

In other words, this language feature allows to import types of an external *module* `'gl-matrix'` from within the *global scope* of your project `.d.ts` file like  this:

```
// ext-module.d.ts, important: don't use ES import statement here
declare module 'vertices-bounding-box' {
  export default function boundingBox(
    positions: Array<import("gl-matrix").vec3>): [number, number]
}
```

Note: A file without ES `import`/`export` is a global script and not a module.

`'vertices-bounding-box'` does not come with its own types, so these need to be declared in a *global script file* as shown above.
For cases, where you wanted to [extend already *existing* types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) like from DefinitelyTyped / `@types`, you would keep the top-level ES import

```
import { vec3 } from 'gl-matrix';
// ...
```

in this file, as module augmentation needs a *module*.